# How to limit chart JS hover to take only one value from each line chart when zoomed out?

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, zooming, mousehover, vue-chartjs

I'm using `chart.js 3.6.1` with VueJS. These are options for particular data I'm having trouble:

```
      hover: {
        mode: 'x',
        intersect: false
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          // not relevant
        },
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          min: minRangeDate.value,
          max: maxRangeDate.value,
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              day: 'dd.MM.',
              hour: 'HH:mm',
              minute: 'HH:mm',
              second: 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
          },
          grid: {
            display: true
          },
          ticks: {
            color: 'white'
          }
        }
      plugins: {
          zoom: {
          pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x',
            modifierKey: 'ctrl'
          },
          zoom: {
            mode: 'x',
            wheel: {
              enabled: true,
              speed: 0.2
            },
            pinch: {
              enabled: true
            }
          },
          limits: {
            x: {
              min: minRangeDate.value,
              max: maxRangeDate.value,
              minRange: 20000 // minimum zoom to seconds
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
```

When the graph is zoomed everything looks fine like in the picture below:
[image: zoomed out chart]

but when the graph is zoomed out hover is picking multiple points which is not desired behavior, pic below:
[image]

And as far as zoom is, the more points hover is picking.
Any idea how to overcome this. I've tried using `'point'` and `'nearest'` but then I get only one data in the tooltip as it is the default behavior.
Also, using `'index'` is not possible because two datasets are not always the same length and it is not logical and desired to compare values by index.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution I came up with, followed by this [ChartJS issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5231) on GitHub. I've made a filter for tooltip and it looks like this now:

```
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          mode: 'x',
          displayColors: false,
          intersect: false,
          filter: function (tooltipItem, currentIndex, tooltipItems) {
            // On zoomed out graph, hovering mouse picks a lot of data for x-axis and displays them all in tooltip.
            // This filter returns only first item from each dataSet from hover picked items passed
            // to tooltip, so it can be correctly displayed in tooltip for different line charts(datasets)
            return tooltipItems[currentIndex].datasetIndex !== tooltipItems[currentIndex - 1]?.datasetIndex
          },
         .
         .
         .
     }
```

Hover still selects multiple data, but the tooltip shows only one for each dataset.